# How to set width of the popup show options list equal width of select box?

Tags: css

I have a problem with selectBox.

```
<select style="width: 200px">
     <option>Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
     <option>Bosnia and Herzegovina, Convertible Marks</option>
</select>
```

Issue: width of popup show options list larger than width of select tag.

And I wants popup show options list will be set width is 200px (as select).

I try to research, but I can't find any solution for this.

Please help me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried style:ing the options as well?

```
select,
select option {
    width: 200px;
}

select option {
    display: block;
}
```